# Positioning <div> element to the left

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm trying to position a div element - the link is titled 'BLANKESQUE' - to the left side. The link to my blogger blog is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com.

I've tried the following 'solutions' but nothing seems to move the text to the left.

```
#dptuh {
position: left;
}

#dptuh {
left:auto;
}

#dptuh {
text-align: left;
}

#dptuh {
float: left;
}
```

I have included the relevant html and css coding below.

```
<div id='dptuh'>
<a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Blankesque</a>
   </div>

#dptuh {
color: #000000;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: cantarell;
font-size: 16px!important;
display: block;
letter-spacing: 0.13em;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0.9%;
  }
#dptuh a {
font-weight: normal;
  }
```

I'd be grateful for any input or even solutions. Thank you in advance.

Iram

Comment: `position: left` is invalid and your element is at the far left of its parent element.  
Gotta check those parents/containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width of **#wctopdropnav** to **100%**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by the styling on the `wctopdropnav` ID. It's floated right with a fixed width, which is what is causing your Blankesque text to push right.

Remove the `float: right` from that class and add a `width: 100%` instead of a fixed width.  You may have to play with margins/padding to get the proper left and right spacing but that should help.

Note, you also don't necessarily need to remove `float: right` either, but the combination of the float and fixed width is what is causing your problem.